# Neo4j - passing string parameters through JavaScript driver doesn't work

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-driver

I am during the process of rewriting **queries** with already injected values to passing `query` and `params` object.

Queries which use ints work fine (I need to use **neo4j's** `int` translation):

```
...
ID(node)=$nodeId
...
LIMIT $fetchLimit
```

```
import { int } from 'neo4j-driver'
...
params = {
  nodeId: int(nodeId)
  fetchLimit: int(fetchLimit)
}
```

In some queries I am searching for strings and I am not using "normal" string search

```
WHERE node.property=$value       <-- "normal" search
WHERE node.property=~"$value.*"  <-- my search
```

**Passing parameters doesn't work in this case.**

I have a feeling that when I pass `value: 'foo'`, neo4j resolves it as below:

```
WHERE node.property=~"$value.*"
...
value: 'foo'

*(injects parameters)*

WHERE node.property=~"'foo'.*"   <-- these inner quotation marks shouldn't be there
```

How to pass strings to this query and expect proper results?

**(note that I am sure that query is written properly because when I directly inject parameters to query using JS's `${value}`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge two strings with `+`. The regular expression after `=~` is just a string.

So, working Cypher would be:

```sql
WHERE node.property =~ $value + ".*"
```

Alternatively, you could assemble the expression string in JavaScript:

```js
search = 'foo'
params = {
  value: `${search}.*`
}
```

```sql
WHERE node.property =~ $value
```